# Biblatex APA-style special issue code shows up in the in-text citation

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa-style

When my citation is from a special issue of a journal, the issue field of my citation contains letters (for example `issue = {S1}`).

The problem is that the issue code shows up in the in-text citation like this:

[image]

How can I make the special issue codes behave like normal issue numbers, only showing up in the bibliography?

Here is the MWE, with the same options I used in my thesis.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber,refsegment=chapter,defernumbers=true,style=apa,url=false,isbn=false,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex} %  
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa} %For utilizing apa style and avoid error in labelmonth and labelday
\AtEveryBibitem{
    \clearfield{labelmonth}
}
\AtEveryBibitem{
    \clearfield{labelday}
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@article{fogliano_vitro_2011,
    langid = {english},
    title = {In Vitro Bioaccessibility and Gut Biotransformation of Polyphenols Present in the Water-Insoluble Cocoa Fraction},
    volume = {55},
    issn = {1613-4133},
    doi = {10.1002/mnfr.201000360},
    issue = {S1},
    journaltitle = {Molecular Nutrition \& Food Research},
    shortjournal = {Mol. Nutr. Food Res.},
    date = {2011-05-01},
    pages = {S44--S55},
    keywords = {Digestion,Flavanols,Phloroglucinolysis,Prebiotic,SCFA},
    author = {Fogliano, Vincenzo and Corollaro, Maria Laura and Vitaglione, Paola and Napolitano, Aurora and Ferracane, Rosalia and Travaglia, Fabiano and Arlorio, Marco and Costabile, Adele and Klinder, Annett and Gibson, Glenn},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document} 
    \parencite{fogliano_vitro_2011}

    \printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{issue}}`. Or use `number` instead of `issue` and ignore the warning about it having to be an integer field.

Comment: Thanks! `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{issue}}`  works, just also deletes the issue field in bibliography. But guess I can survive that:)

Comment: Really? I can't check at the moment, but that code should really just delete the issue in the citation. It should still be there in the bibliography.

Comment: Ahhh, I see the `issue` doesn't appear in the bibliography with your code either.

Comment: Yes, just tested here, and same results, issue does not go to the bibliography in the original code.

Comment: See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/45

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `number` field instead of `issue`

```
@article{fogliano_vitro_2011,
  langid       = {english},
  title        = {In Vitro Bioaccessibility and Gut Biotransformation of Polyphenols Present in the Water-Insoluble Cocoa Fraction},
  volume       = {55},
  doi          = {10.1002/mnfr.201000360},
  number       = {S1},
  journaltitle = {Molecular Nutrition \& Food Research},
  date         = {2011-05-01},
  pages        = {S44--S55},
  author       = {Fogliano, Vincenzo and Corollaro, Maria Laura and Vitaglione, Paola and Napolitano, Aurora and Ferracane, Rosalia and Travaglia, Fabiano and Arlorio, Marco and Costabile, Adele and Klinder, Annett and Gibson, Glenn},
}
```

**The go-to subdivision of a `volume` for `@article` entries has always been `number` and *not* `issue`** (regardless of whether the journal called the subdivision of `volume` "number" or "issue" themselves).

`number` was, however, an integer field and so some people and some reference software refrained from using `number` for values such as "S1" and used `issue` instead. Following discussions in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/726, `number` is not an integer field any more and the `biblatex` documentation from version 3.12 onwards explicitly encourages using the `number` field even for non-integer values.

> Normally [the `number`] field will be an integer or an integer range, but in certain cases it may also contain “S1”, “Suppl. 1”, in these cases the output should be scrutinised carefully.

`issue` should only be used for more verbose identifiers such as "Spring"/"Summer" or "Michaelmas term".

> The placement of `issue` is similar to `month` and `number`, integer
>   ranges and short designators are better written to the `number` field.

See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/45 and [Biblatex doesn't recognize the journal's issue number when filled by a non-numeric value](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418590/35864)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex} 

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{fogliano_vitro_2011,
  langid       = {english},
  title        = {In Vitro Bioaccessibility and Gut Biotransformation of Polyphenols Present in the Water-Insoluble Cocoa Fraction},
  volume       = {55},
  doi          = {10.1002/mnfr.201000360},
  number       = {S1},
  journaltitle = {Molecular Nutrition \& Food Research},
  date         = {2011-05-01},
  pages        = {S44--S55},
  author       = {Fogliano, Vincenzo and Corollaro, Maria Laura and Vitaglione, Paola and Napolitano, Aurora and Ferracane, Rosalia and Travaglia, Fabiano and Arlorio, Marco and Costabile, Adele and Klinder, Annett and Gibson, Glenn},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document} 
  \parencite{fogliano_vitro_2011}
  \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image]