# Biblatex doesn't recognize the journal's issue number when filled by a non-numeric value

Tags: biblatex

Sometimes, academic journal are published in a double issues. It results, in the .bib file, a reference with a field 'number' which is not set to '2' or '3', for instance, but set to '2-3'.

Here is what biblatex+biber gives :

> SURNAME Name, "A Nice Title", Annual Review of Something 10 (2-3 1996).

Here is what I want to get :

> SURNAME Name, "A Nice Title", Annual Review of Something. 10.2-3 (1996).

I precise that everything works well when the field 'number' of my .bib file is set with a value specifically numeric.

What's happening ?

[EDIT]

We've discussed on this issue on the github of the Zotero plugin called  Better bibtex ([here](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/issues/925#issuecomment-370804690)). A first step in answer is that such a functionning is normal. Indeed, the biblatex manual says (section 2.2.2) :

> **issue field (literal)**
>
> The issue of a journal. This field is intended for journals whose individual issues are identified by a designation such as ‘Spring’ or ‘Summer’ rather than the month or a number. Since the placement of issue is similar to month and number, this field may also be useful with double issues and other special cases. See also month, number, and § 2.3.9.
>
> [...]
>
> **number: field (integer)**
>
> The number of a journal or the volume/number of a book in a series. See also issue as well as §§2.3.7 and 2.3.9. With @patent entries, this is the number or record token of a patent or patent request. It is expected to be an integer, not necessarily in arabic numerals since biber will automatically from roman numerals or arabic letter to integers internally for sorting purposes.

So it appears that Biblatex requires a integer value in the field `number`. If necessary, it recommends to avoid this limitation in using the field `issue`.

The problem remains that double issues **do not render properly** in this way.

Here is an example :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setmainlanguage{french}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bob1996,
  title = {A {{Very Nice Title}}},
  volume = {10},
  number = {2},
  journaltitle = {Annual Review of Nothing},
  date = {1996},
  author = {Bob, Bob}
}

@article{John1996,
  title = {A {{Nice Title}}},
  volume = {10},
  issue = {2-3},
  journaltitle = {Annual Review of Something},
  date = {1996},
  author = {John, John}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[ 
backend=biber,citestyle=verbose,bibstyle=verbose,]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\begin{document}
Here is something\autocite{Bob1996} very interesting\autocite{John1996}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

What gives (with xelatex+biber) :

> Bob, Bob. “A Very Nice Title”. In : Annual Review of Nothing 10.2 (1996).
>
> John, John. “A Nice Title”. In : Annual Review of Something 10 (2-3 1996).

Comment: This is not the standard behaviour of the standard styles. What style do you use? Can you show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). The answer will crucially depend on the style you use and its exact implementation of the number field format.

Comment: Some `biblatex` styles test if the field is a number before they put a 'vol.', 'no.' or 'edition' into the format. But there are several different tests a style could use `\ifinteger`, `\ifnumeral`, `\ifnumerals`, or their `\iffield...` versions (depending on the context). The styles also vary where they do these tests: In the field format (usually this is the best place) or in a different bibmacro (there may be cases where this is cleverer solution).

Comment: Thank you. I tried to make MWEB and I didn't manage to repoduce my problem ! I've looked for deeper and it appears that I've not a problem with biblatex formating but with the exporting process in .bib. If I fill the number field with '2-3', the field name turns from 'number' to 'issue'. If I correct it manually, everything fall into place. So, I'm going to ask what's happens in the Zotero forum...

Comment: We *need* to know the `biblatex` style you use. Show us an MWE/MWEB (see links in my first comment). While the `biblatex` documentation and Biber want an integer in the `number` field, you can get away not using an integer there in certain cases. `issue` is certainly a worse choice for input such as `2-3`.

Comment: Of course, but I needed few minutes more to make it. Here it is.

Comment: Zotero BTT 5.0.111 with the relevant changes from https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/issues/925 should be out now. Please test it and report back.

Comment: Done. Everything's fine now. Thank for your contribution to the solution ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `biblatex` there are two possible fields to indicate the subdivision of a `volume` for `@article` and `@periodical` entries: `number` and `issue`. **The go-to field is `number`** and for most users that is the appropriate field **even if the publisher calls the subdivision of a volume "issue"**. The `issue` field is printed closer to the date in the standard styles and can be used in case the `number` field gives unfortunate output.

In `biblatex` versions before 3.12 `number` was an integer field. This caused some export tools such as [Better Bib(La)TeX for Zotero](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex) to only export integer values to `number` and use `issue` as a fallback for non-integer values. Since `2-3` is not an integer it was exported to `issue`. The output for `number = {2-3}` is also acceptable and arguably nicer than with `issue = {2-3}`, so it was decided that `number` should not be restricted to integer input any more: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/726

The documentation for 3.12 states

> Normally [the `number`] field will be an integer or an integer range, but in certain cases it may also contain “S1”, “Suppl. 1”, in these cases the output should be scrutinised carefully.

While for `issue` it reads

> The placement of `issue` is similar to `month` and `number`, integer
>   ranges and short designators are better written to the `number` field.

`issue` still makes sense for more verbose identifiers such as "Spring"/"Summer" or "Michaelmas term".

Starting from version 5.0.111 BBT exports integer ranges and a few other short designators to `number` as well, see https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/issues/925. This gives the expected output in your case.

So you'll now get

```
@article{John1996,
  title        = {A Nice Title},
  volume       = {10},
  number       = {2-3},
  journaltitle = {Annual Review of Something},
  date         = {1996},
  author       = {John, John}
}
```

which will yield

> John, John. “A Nice Title”. In: Annual Review of Something 10.2-3 (1996).

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414495/35864

Comment: That resumes perfectly the whole discussion and its conclusion. Thank for having taken the time to write it !