# biblatex+biber: issue={4es} or number={4es}?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber, journal-publishing, journal

Let's assume we want to cite the article

https://doi.org/10.1145/242224.242385

Our LaTeX document contains

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sortcites=true,maxbibnames=99,useprefix=true,dateabbrev=true]{biblatex}
```

Both DBLP and the publisher's Web page concerning the document suggest `number = {4es}` for BibTeX.  However, we use `biber` in this question. Would the answer stay the same (and "4es" considered a "short designator"), or would we switch to `issue = {4es}`?

Comment: `number` and `issue` are not the same, although it's not entirely clear to me how certain journals choose these two.  What is the problem you are trying to solve?  Is it that `biber` is complaining about `4es` not being only digits?

Comment: I see there is one work citing this paper.  I don't have access to the full text but maybe you can pull it up and check how it is cited there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely

```
number = {4es},
```

'4es' is a prime example of what those who wrote the 'short designator' passage in the `biblatex` manual had in mind. In fact `4es` is even analogue to the example `S1` mentioned in the manual (`S1` is 'supplement 1' and according to [the ACM digital library page of *ACM Computing Surveys*](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=J204&preflayout=flat) the `es` in `4es` stands for 'electronic supplement').

In general, if one has to decide between `number` and `issue`, `number` is going to be the better choice. `issue` is almost never what people want.

A good rule of thumb is that `number` modifies (or subdivides) `volume`, while `issue` modifies the publication year. That's why examples of sensible `issue` usage almost always revolve around terms like `issue = {Summer},` or `issue = {Michaelmas term},`. Numeric and semi-numeric identifiers like `4es`, `S1` modify the `volume` and should go into `number`.

In older versions of `biblatex`, `number` was listed as an integer field, which made some of those who read the documentation shy away from putting `S1` or `4es` in the `number` field. But that was changed following https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/726 and some discussion on this site ([Biblatex doesn't recognize the journal's issue number when filled by a non-numeric value](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418590/35864), [Biblatex APA-style special issue code shows up in the in-text citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414495/35864)) and elsewhere. Of course you now can't enjoy numeric sorting by `number`, but you can't have your cake and eat it too. (It is possible to turn `number` back to an integer field in a custom data model. Technically speaking sorting of non-integer values would not be well-defined in that case, though, and so values like `4es` should be avoided.)

<sub>Small aside: Whether you use BibTeX or Biber as backend for `biblatex` does not matter for this question. What matters is that you use `biblatex` and not BibTeX and its `.bst` styles. So the dichotomy is not 'BibTeX vs. Biber' it is 'BibTeX vs. `biblatex`'. For the majority of the `biblatex` data model and the general meaning of fields it does not matter whether you use BibTeX or Biber, but of course there are details where the two backends differ (think data model customisability, data inheritance, date field parsing, ...).</sub>

Comment: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/1f71483eb2ad5d4c46227b09a722854bab101f24