# Why my bibliographic is not being parsed with this author name?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testbib.bib}
@article{quantumComputerSurvey,
    author = {Yoshito Kanamori, Seong-Moo Yoo, W. D. Pan, F. T. Sheldon},
    title = {A short survey on quantum computers},
    journal = {International Journal of Computers and Applications},
    volume = {28},
    issue = {3},
    year = {2019},
    issn = {1925-7074},
    url = {https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228613051_A_short_survey_on_quantum_computers},
    doi = {10.2316/Journal.202.2006.3.202-1700},
    publisher = {ACTA Press},
    address = {2451 Dieppe Ave SW, Calgary, AB, Canada},
    keywords = {Classical computers, quantum computers, quantum computer systems, quantum simulators, Shor's algorithm},
    abstract = {Quantum computing is an emerging technology. The clock frequency
    of current computer processor systems may reach about 40 GHz within the next
    10 years. By then, one atom may represent one bit. Electrons under such
    conditions are no longer described by classical physics, and a new model of
    the computer may be necessary by that time. The quantum computer is one
    proposal that may have merit in dealing with the problems presented.
    Currently, there exist some algorithms utilizing the advantage of quantum
    computers. For example, Shor's algorithm performs factoring of a large
    integer in polynomial time, whereas classical factoring algorithms can do it
    in exponential time. In this paper we briey survey the current status of
    quantum computers, quantum computer systems, and quantum simulators.},
}
\end{filecontents}

\appto{\bibsetup}{\raggedright}
\bibliography{testbib.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{quantumComputerSurvey}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Every time I try to parse the above bibliography, it ways shows this:

[image]

This is the full latex log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6400) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.8.23)  29 JUN 2019 01:00
entering extended mode
**./test1.tex
(test1.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.12> and hyphenation patterns for 76 language(s) loaded.
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2016/05/16 v3.7f configurable book, report, article document class
\onelineskip=\skip41
\lxvchars=\skip42
\xlvchars=\skip43
\@memcnta=\count79
\c@@memmarkcntra=\count80
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\ifetex\ifetex.sty
Package: ifetex 2011/12/15 v1.2 ifetex
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\plain\ifetex\ifetex.tex)) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
\stockheight=\skip44
\stockwidth=\skip45
\trimtop=\skip46
\trimedge=\skip47
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\mem10.clo
File: mem10.clo 2008/01/30 v0.3 memoir class 10pt size option
)
\binding=\skip48
...
\cfttablenumwidth=\skip184
Package abstract [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package appendix [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package array [2008/09/09] emulated by memoir.
Package booktabs [2016/05/16] emulated by memoir.
Package ccaption [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package changepage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package chngcntr [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package chngpage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package crop emulated by memoir.
Package dcolumn [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package delarray [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package enumerate [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package epigraph [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package ifmtarg [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package index [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package makeidx [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package moreverb [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package mparhack [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package needspace [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package newfile [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package nextpage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package pagenote [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package parskip [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package patchcmd [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package setspace [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package shortvrb [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package showidx [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tabularx [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package titleref [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package titling [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocbibind [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocloft [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocvsec2 [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package verbatim [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package verse [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\mempatch.sty
Package: mempatch 2009/07/24 v6.0f Patches for memoir class v1.6180339
)) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2016/12/05 v3.7 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count137
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks22
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
))) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.sty
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count138
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.def
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
)) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\xstring\xstring.sty (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\xstring\xstring.tex
\@xs@message=\write4
\integerpart=\count139
\decimalpart=\count140
)
Package: xstring 2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count141
\c@listtotal=\count142
\c@listcount=\count143
\c@liststart=\count144
\c@liststop=\count145
\c@citecount=\count146
\c@citetotal=\count147
\c@multicitecount=\count148
\c@multicitetotal=\count149
\c@instcount=\count150
\c@maxnames=\count151
\c@minnames=\count152
\c@maxitems=\count153
\c@minitems=\count154
\c@citecounter=\count155
\c@savedcitecounter=\count156
\c@uniquelist=\count157
\c@uniquename=\count158
\c@refsection=\count159
\c@refsegment=\count160
\c@maxextratitle=\count161
\c@maxextratitleyear=\count162
\c@maxextrayear=\count163
\c@maxextraalpha=\count164
\c@abbrvpenalty=\count165
\c@highnamepenalty=\count166
\c@lownamepenalty=\count167
\c@maxparens=\count168
\c@parenlevel=\count169
\blx@tempcnta=\count170
\blx@tempcntb=\count171
\blx@tempcntc=\count172
\blx@maxsection=\count173
\blx@maxsegment@0=\count174
\blx@notetype=\count175
\blx@parenlevel@text=\count176
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count177
\blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count178
\labelnumberwidth=\skip185
\labelalphawidth=\skip186
\biblabelsep=\skip187
\bibnamesep=\skip188
\bibinitsep=\skip189
\bibparsep=\skip190
\bibhang=\skip191
\blx@bcfin=\read2
\blx@bcfout=\write5
\c@mincomprange=\count179
\c@maxcomprange=\count180
\c@mincompwidth=\count181
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-dm.def)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex style data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'authoryear.dbx' not found.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count182
\c@savedafterword=\count183
\c@annotator=\count184
\c@savedannotator=\count185
\c@author=\count186
\c@savedauthor=\count187
\c@bookauthor=\count188
\c@savedbookauthor=\count189
\c@commentator=\count190
\c@savedcommentator=\count191
\c@editor=\count192
\c@savededitor=\count193
\c@editora=\count194
\c@savededitora=\count266
\c@editorb=\count267
\c@savededitorb=\count268
\c@editorc=\count269
\c@savededitorc=\count270
\c@foreword=\count271
\c@savedforeword=\count272
\c@holder=\count273
\c@savedholder=\count274
\c@introduction=\count275
\c@savedintroduction=\count276
\c@namea=\count277
\c@savednamea=\count278
\c@nameb=\count279
\c@savednameb=\count280
\c@namec=\count281
\c@savednamec=\count282
\c@translator=\count283
\c@savedtranslator=\count284
\c@shortauthor=\count285
\c@savedshortauthor=\count286
\c@shorteditor=\count287
\c@savedshorteditor=\count288
\c@labelname=\count289
\c@savedlabelname=\count290
\c@institution=\count291
\c@savedinstitution=\count292
\c@lista=\count293
\c@savedlista=\count294
\c@listb=\count295
\c@savedlistb=\count296
\c@listc=\count297
\c@savedlistc=\count298
\c@listd=\count299
\c@savedlistd=\count300
\c@liste=\count301
\c@savedliste=\count302
\c@listf=\count303
\c@savedlistf=\count304
\c@location=\count305
\c@savedlocation=\count306
\c@organization=\count307
\c@savedorganization=\count308
\c@origlocation=\count309
\c@savedoriglocation=\count310
\c@origpublisher=\count311
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count312
\c@publisher=\count313
\c@savedpublisher=\count314
\c@language=\count315
\c@savedlanguage=\count316
\c@pageref=\count317
\c@savedpageref=\count318
\shorthandwidth=\skip192
\shortjournalwidth=\skip193
\shortserieswidth=\skip194
\shorttitlewidth=\skip256
\shortauthorwidth=\skip257
\shorteditorwidth=\skip258
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-compat.def
File: blx-compat.def 2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.def
File: biblatex.def 2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
\c@textcitecount=\count319
\c@textcitetotal=\count320
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count321
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count322
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count323
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count324
\c@smartand=\count325
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'authoryear'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'authoryear.bbx' found.
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\authoryear.bbx
File: authoryear.bbx 2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\standard.bbx
File: standard.bbx 2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count326
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count327
))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'authoryear'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'authoryear.cbx' found.
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\biblatex\cbx\authoryear.cbx
File: authoryear.cbx 2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
)) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\filecontents\filecontents.sty
Package: filecontents 2011/10/08 v1.3 Create an external file from within a LaTeX document
)

LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file `./testbib.bib'.

\openout15 = `testbib.bib'.


Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\biblatex\lbx\english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
)
\@quotelevel=\count328
\@quotereset=\count329
 (F:\SublimeText\Data\Cache\LaTeXTools\2071ecb882505329020c982855db3b0e\test1.aux)
\openout1 = `test1.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
Package biblatex Info: No input encoding detected.
(biblatex)             Assuming 'ascii'.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'ascii'.
\openout5 = `test1.bcf'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'test1.bbl' found.
 (F:\SublimeText\Data\Cache\LaTeXTools\2071ecb882505329020c982855db3b0e\test1.bbl)
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 36.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 36.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'quantumComputerSurvey' on page 1 undefined on input line 37.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 38.

[1{D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/data/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}

] (F:\SublimeText\Data\Cache\LaTeXTools\2071ecb882505329020c982855db3b0e\test1.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                test1
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'test1.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `test1.run.xml'.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10325 strings out of 493314
 171622 string characters out of 3134142
 620090 words of memory out of 3000000
 13839 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 4899 words of font info for 18 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 39i,10n,30p,876b,698s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on F:\SublimeText\Data\Cache\LaTeXTools\2071ecb882505329020c982855db3b0e\test1.pdf (1 page, 20618 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 14 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

It keeps telling-me, `Please (re)run Biber on the file`, and I re-run, re-run, ... and it never works.

But if I remove the author `Seong-Moo Yoo,` from the list, then, it works correctly:

[image]

Why my bibliographic entry is never parsed?

This is the full log, from latex when I removed the `Seong-Moo Yoo,` author name and it worked correclty as on the image just above:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6400) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.8.23)  29 JUN 2019 01:03
entering extended mode
**./test1.tex
(test1.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.12> and hyphenation patterns for 76 language(s) loaded.
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2016/05/16 v3.7f configurable book, report, article document class
\onelineskip=\skip41
\lxvchars=\skip42
\xlvchars=\skip43
\@memcnta=\count79
\c@@memmarkcntra=\count80
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\ifetex\ifetex.sty
Package: ifetex 2011/12/15 v1.2 ifetex
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\plain\ifetex\ifetex.tex)) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
\stockheight=\skip44
\stockwidth=\skip45
\trimtop=\skip46
\trimedge=\skip47
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\mem10.clo
File: mem10.clo 2008/01/30 v0.3 memoir class 10pt size option
)
\binding=\skip48
...
\c@cp@cntr=\count118
LaTeX Info: Redefining \: on input line 12068.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \! on input line 12070.
\c@ism@mctr=\count119
...
\cfttableindent=\skip183
\cfttablenumwidth=\skip184
Package abstract [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
...
Package verbatim [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package verse [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\mempatch.sty
Package: mempatch 2009/07/24 v6.0f Patches for memoir class v1.6180339
)) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2016/12/05 v3.7 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count137
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks22
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
))) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.sty
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count138
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.def
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
)) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\xstring\xstring.sty (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\xstring\xstring.tex
\@xs@message=\write4
\integerpart=\count139
\decimalpart=\count140
)
Package: xstring 2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count141
...
\c@mincompwidth=\count181
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-dm.def)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex style data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'authoryear.dbx' not found.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count182
...
\shorteditorwidth=\skip258
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-compat.def
File: blx-compat.def 2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.def
File: biblatex.def 2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
\c@textcitecount=\count319
\c@textcitetotal=\count320
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count321
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count322
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count323
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count324
\c@smartand=\count325
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'authoryear'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'authoryear.bbx' found.
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\authoryear.bbx
File: authoryear.bbx 2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\standard.bbx
File: standard.bbx 2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count326
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count327
))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'authoryear'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'authoryear.cbx' found.
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\biblatex\cbx\authoryear.cbx
File: authoryear.cbx 2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
...
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
)) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\filecontents\filecontents.sty
Package: filecontents 2011/10/08 v1.3 Create an external file from within a LaTeX document
)

LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file `./testbib.bib'.

\openout15 = `testbib.bib'.


Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\biblatex\lbx\english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
)
\@quotelevel=\count328
\@quotereset=\count329
 (F:\SublimeText\Data\Cache\LaTeXTools\2071ecb882505329020c982855db3b0e\test1.aux)
\openout1 = `test1.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 36.
Package biblatex Info: No input encoding detected.
(biblatex)             Assuming 'ascii'.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'ascii'.
\openout5 = `test1.bcf'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'test1.bbl' found.
 (F:\SublimeText\Data\Cache\LaTeXTools\2071ecb882505329020c982855db3b0e\test1.bbl)
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 36.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 36.
 [1{D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/data/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}

] [2

]
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 38.
 [3] (F:\SublimeText\Data\Cache\LaTeXTools\2071ecb882505329020c982855db3b0e\test1.aux)
Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'test1.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `test1.run.xml'.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10365 strings out of 493314
 172388 string characters out of 3134142
 621113 words of memory out of 3000000
 13875 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 6012 words of font info for 22 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 44i,10n,45p,894b,1205s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmcsc10.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
Output written on F:\SublimeText\Data\Cache\LaTeXTools\2071ecb882505329020c982855db3b0e\test1.pdf (3 pages, 66403 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 32 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

How Can I keep the `Seong-Moo Yoo,` author name on my bibliographic list?

I reproduced this same problem on Windows and Linux with these latex versions:

```
$ tex --version
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.

$ tex --version
MiKTeX-TeX 2.9.6300 (3.14159265) (MiKTeX 2.9.6400)
Copyright (C) 1982 by D. E. Knuth; all rights are reserved.
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
using bzip2 version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
compiled with curl version 7.54.1; using libcurl/7.54.1 WinSSL
compiled with expat version 2.2; using expat_2.2.0
compiled with liblzma version 50020032; using 50020032
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 2.5.3; using LibreSSL 2.5.3
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 2.6416; using 2.6416
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 2.6413; using 2.6413
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 1.6300; using 1.6300
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 1.6403; using 1.6403
compiled with uriparser version 0.8.4
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
```

Comment: Multiple names in name fields like `author` and `editor` must be separated with `and` regardless of the desired output. `author = {Yoshito Kanamori, Seong-Moo Yoo, W. D. Pan, F. T. Sheldon},` is incorrect, it should probably be `author = {Yoshito Kanamori and Seong-Moo Yoo and W. D. Pan and F. T. Sheldon},` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864.

Comment: @moewe, It worked! Thanks!

Comment: The fact that things appear to work if you remove one of the names from the list comes from the name parsing rules (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864). A single name may contain up to three commas that separate the family, junior part and given name. In that case the list would be parsed as a single name and each name from the list would be interpreted as a different name oart, which is not what you want.

Comment: Hrmpf, of course a name may only contain up to *two commas* that separate *three 'groups'* (which contain exactly one name part for the given name and junior part, the first group may contain the von part and the family name).

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I had it wrong because so far all my other bibliographies are copy and paste from the `Export to Biblatex` buttons on journals as https://dl.acm.org/. But this article website did not have such button and I built the bibliography by hand, i.e, typing it. And I miserably missed the fact that authors names are separated by `and` instead of `,`

Comment: Ah yes, export functions usually get those things right, but it is always good to double check what they produce https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/35864

Comment: Just a minor thing: `issue = {3},` should probably be `number = {3},`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354759/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474281/35864. The `publisher `and `address` fields are usually ignored by `biblatex` for the `@article` type, but you probably don't want to give the full address of the publisher in `address`/`location`: usually the city suffices.