# Biblatex printing weird citations via \citep{} within APA

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

When using the APA style to automate my citations, it prints out with a ", 2" or a ", 1" at the end, as if it's supposed to be a page or paragraph number. After reviewing my bib file, I strongly suspect biblatex is printing out the issue number.

My MWE LaTeX file is:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}

%document formatting
\usepackage[margin = 2.5cm]{geometry}

%mathematical packages
\usepackage{amsfonts,mathtools,amssymb, amsthm}

%Referencing package
\usepackage[
    backend = biber,
    style = apa,
    natbib = true
    ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citations.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Leibniz and Cauchy rejected imaginary numbers \citep{IForImagNumb}.

Originally used to solve specific inputs for the cubic formula roughly five centuries ago \citep{IForImagNumb,BriefHistOfeigamma,HistOfMaths}.

\citet{ImagXtrmNumb} has developed ``imaginary extreme numbers".

\citet{PhysNatureOfImagNumb} has claimed to find physical existence of imaginary, complex, and hypercomplex numbers.
```

My MWE bib file is:

```
@book{HistOfMaths,
    author = {Boyer, Carl B. and Merzbch, Uta C.},
    year = {1991},
    title = {A history of mathematics},
    edition = {2nd},
    city = {New York},
    publisher = {Wiley}
}

@article{BriefHistOfeigamma,
    author = {Debnath, Lokenath},
    year = {2015},
    title = {A brief history of the most remarkable numbers e, i, and {$\gamma$} in mathematical sciences with applications},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Mathematical Education in Science and Technology},
    volume = {46},
    issue = {6},
    pages = {853-878},
    doi = {10.1080/0020739X.2015.1015266}
}

@article{IForImagNumb,
    author = {Curcio, Liliana},
    year = {2017},
    title = {I for Imaginary Numbers},
    journaltitle = {Lettera Mathematica},
    volume = {5},
    issue = {2},
    pages = {125-129},
    doi = {10.1007/s40329-017-0172-6}
}

@article{PhysNatureOfImagNumb,
    author = {Antonov, Alexander Alexandrovich},
    year = {2016},
    title = {Physical Reality and Nature of Imaginary, Complex and Hypercomplex Numbers},
    journaltitle = {General Mathematics Notes},
    volume = {35},
    issue = {2},
    pages = {40-63},
    url = {http://www.geman.in/yahoo_site_admin/assets/docs/4_GMN-10932-V35N2.31895146.pdf}
}

@article{ImagXtrmNumb,
    author = {Liu, Liping},
    year = {2013},
    title = {Imaginary numbers for combining linear equation models via Dempster's rule},
    journaltitle = {International Journal of Approximate Reasoning},
    volume = {55},
    issue = {1},
    pages = {294-310},
    doi = {10.1016/j.ijar.2013.09.004}
}
```

For some weird reason, biblatex prints out the following:

- "(Curcio, 2017, 2)" for `\citep{IForImagNumb}`,
- "(Boyer & Merzbch, 1991; Curcio, 2017, 2; Debnath, 2015, 6)" for `\citep{IForImagNumb,BriefHistOfeigamma,HistOfMaths}`,
- "Liu (2013, 1)" for `\citet{ImagXtrmNumb}`, and
- "Antonov (2016, 2)" for `\citet{PhysNatureOfImagNumb}`.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Don't use the `issue` field to give the issue number of a journal article, that information belongs into the `number` field. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414495/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354759/35864

Comment: @moewe well, that's counter-intuitive. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'll leave this up for a day if anyone wants to write an answer that I can approve. Otherwise, I'll take this question

Comment: A bit counter-intuitive, yes. Back in the BibTeX times there was no `ìssue` and people knew they had to use `number`, but with `biblatex` also offering an `issue` people get confused. Would you not say that your question is a duplicate of the one I linked? To me it seems they are exactly the same and so it would make sense to close this one as a duplicate. Certainly if I were to write an answer it would pretty much look like the one I wrote for the other question (modulo different examples).

Comment: @moewe fair enough. How do I delete my questions, or can only moderators do that?

Comment: Since you agree your question is a duplicate I have marked it as such. The advantage of marking your question as a duplicate over deleting is that it remains searchable and may help others with a similar issue find the answer with different search terms.